# Autocompleting locations

Tags: vb.net

Can this function be cleaner? It looks to me that I have too much nesting (`Using` + `If` + `While`).

```vb
Public Shared Function GetLocationsAutocomplete(ByRef userData As IUser, ByVal prefix As String) As List(Of AutocompleteItem)
    Dim conn As DbConnection = DbProvider.GetDbConnection(ConnectionStringHelper.GetConnectionString(userData))
    Dim retValue As List(Of AutocompleteItem) = Nothing

    Const SQL As String = " SELECT DISTINCT TOP 20 Location " & _
                          " FROM userdetailstable WHERE ClientID=@ClientID " & _
                          " AND Location IS NOT NULL AND LEN(Location) > 0 AND Location LIKE @Filter "
    Try
        conn.Open()
        Logger.WriteConnectionInfo("UserDataAccess.GetLocationsAutocomplete", Logger.ConnectionActionType.Opened)

        ' Getting data from DB:
        Using cmd As DbCommand = DbProvider.GetDbCommand(SQL, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClientID", DbType.Int32).Value = userData.ClientID
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Filter", DbType.String).Value = String.Format("%{0}%", prefix)
            Using reader As DbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                If reader.HasRows Then
                    retValue = New List(Of AutocompleteItem)
                    ' Populate retValue list with project names:
                    Dim item As AutocompleteItem = Nothing
                    While reader.Read()
                        item = New AutocompleteItem()
                        item.Value = reader.GetString("Location")
                        item.Label = item.Value
                        retValue.Add(item)
                    End While
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    Finally
        conn.Close()
        conn.Dispose()
        Logger.WriteConnectionInfo("SearchDataAccess.GetLocationsAutocomplete", Logger.ConnectionActionType.Closed)
    End Try

    Return retValue

End Function
```

Answer (score 8):

Your comments should actually give you a hint.

> ```
> ' Getting data from DB:
> ' ...
> ' Populate retValue list with project names:
> ```

These sound like the beginnings of good function names to me.

```vb
Private Function GetAutocompleteItems(reader as DbDataReader) as List(Of AutocompleteItem)
    If reader.HasRows Then
        retValue = New List(Of AutocompleteItem)
        ' Populate retValue list with project names:
        Dim item As AutocompleteItem = Nothing
        While reader.Read()
            item = New AutocompleteItem()
            item.Value = reader.GetString("Location")
            item.Label = item.Value
            retValue.Add(item)
        End While
    End If

    Return retValue
End Function
```

Which would then be called like this.

```vb
        ' Getting data from DB:
        Using cmd As DbCommand = DbProvider.GetDbCommand(SQL, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClientID", DbType.Int32).Value = userData.ClientID
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Filter", DbType.String).Value = String.Format("%{0}%", prefix)
            Using reader As DbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                retValue = GetAutocompleteItems(reader)
            End Using
        End Using
```

As you can see, just extracting this one function out considerably reduced the nesting.

---

I don't see much else to pick on other than this.

> ```
>     Finally
>         conn.Close()
>         conn.Dispose()
>         Logger.WriteConnectionInfo("SearchDataAccess.GetLocationsAutocomplete", Logger.ConnectionActionType.Closed)
>     End Try
> ```

`DbConnection` obviously implements `IDisposable`, so why not use another `Using` block?